# Trying to create y=mx+c graph with Matplotlib on python but the graph doesn't show up after user input

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run my code the matplotlib window crashes after user input, Here is the python code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random

class DataGenerator:

    def value(x_min, x_max) -> int:

        return random.randint(x_min,x_max)

    def generator(x_min,x_max) -> int:

        data = [dataGenerator.value(x_min,x_max) for _ in range(20)]

        m = (x_max - x_min)

        c = x_min

        y = []

        for x in data:

            values = ((m*x) + c)

            y.append(values)

        plt.plot(y,data)

        plt.show

x_min = int(input("Enter the minimum value "))
    
x_max = int(input("Enter the maximum value "))

dataGenerator = DataGenerator

dataGenerator.generator(x_min, x_max)
```

Comment: What was the user input? What error message did you get?

Comment: Typo.  You have `plt.show` where you meant to have `plt.show()`.  You aren't calling the function.

Comment: `plt.show` wouldn't cause a "crash" though, so either that's worded poorly or we need more details like the user input and error traceback.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: There is no need to create `dataGenerator`. You should use `DataGenerator` instead of `dataGenerator` because it will be more readable. With `dataGenerator` we can expect instance of `DataGenerator`.

Comment: @tdy I realized this after digging in code :)